# Альтернативное решение

Tags: javascript, массивы

Была задача, взять каждый элемент массива и посчитать сколько элементов справа от него будет меньше

```js
function smaller(arr) {
  let res = []

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let counter = 0

    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + j]) {
        counter += 1
      }
    }
    res.push(counter)
  }
  console.log(res)
}

smaller([5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]) // output [4,1,5,5,0,0,0,0,0]
```

можно решить эту задачу с помощью методов массива ? какой сюда лучше подойдет?

Comment: обрати внимание, что в своем коде во втором цикле ты делаешь лишние итерации. Нет смысла проверять весь массив, если тебе нужны элементы с индексом больше текущего

Comment: @Grundy понял. можно было сделать j = i+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу можно разбить на две части:

1. поставить в соответствие каждому элементу массива - число. Для этого подойдет метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. посчитать количество элементов меньше данного. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
3. взять элементы правее данного. Для этого можно использовать метод [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
function smaller(arr) {
  let res = arr.map((el, index) => arr.slice(index).filter(e => el > e).length)

  console.log(res)
}

smaller([5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]) // output [4,1,5,5,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Благодарю! буду гуглить и разбираться

Answer (score 0):

какое-то такое можно

```js
function smaller2(arr){
  return arr.map(function(el, idx, arr){    
        return arr.slice(idx).filter(v => v < el).length;
     });
}

console.log(smaller2([5,4,7,9,2,4,4,5,6]));
```

Comment: можно вместо `filter+length` сделать `reduce` с подсчетом.

Comment: Благодарю !
(v => v < el) - как можно это расшифровать ?)

Comment: @Haid, сравниваешь элементы просто.

Comment: @teran, лучше разные имена давать параметрам, а то потом путаница будет где какой `arr`, даже несмотря на то, что тут это одно и то же